# React Native Unable to relaunch keyboard for text input after back button pressed

Tags: android, react-native

I am having problems with my text input component in React Native Android.

If I press the back button (device), the text input stays focused and I cannot click to relaunch the keyboard.

How do I resolve this? I have handled onSubmitEditing and onEndEditing which works fine with the "Done" button. But back messes it up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be useful if you share the code you have tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, not sure what it is caused by but I solved using this.

```
var {DeviceEventEmitter} = require('react-native')
var dismissKeyboard = require('react-native-dismiss-keyboard')

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidHide', dismissKeyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire the keyboard dismiss action in a keyboardWillHide event

```js
 this.keyboardWillHide = Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
                Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide) :
                Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
```

then in the keyboardWillHide callback , insert the keyboard.dismiss function

```js
keyboardWillHide = () => {
       // some code
        Keyboard.dismiss();
    };
```

That's work for me in 2021